# Sort the li list using class name in jquery?

Tags: jquery, user-interface

My code is:

```
<ul class="ui-multiselect-checkboxes ui-helper-reset" style="height: 175px;">
<li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-0" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-0" name="multiselect_name" value="Abkhazian" title="Abkhazian" type="checkbox"><span>Abkhazian</span></label>
</li>
<li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-1" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-1" name="multiselect_name" value="Afar" title="Afar" type="checkbox"><span>Afar</span></label>
</li>
<li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-2" title="" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-hover">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-2" name="mmultiselect_name" value="Afrikaans" title="Afrikaans" type="checkbox"><span>Afrikaans</span></label>
</li>
<li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-3" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-3" name="multiselect_name" value="Albanian" title="Albanian" type="checkbox"><span>Albanian</span></label> </li>
<li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-4" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-4" name="multiselect_name" value="Amharic" title="Amharic" type="checkbox"><span>Amharic</span></label>
</li>
```

If i click the checkbox. Then it should be on top. How to do using jquery?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code... On click of a checkbox, if it is `checked`, it moves up to first position in the list.

I'm using an [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to do this without a class...

```js
$("[type='checkbox']").on("click",function(){
  if( $(this).is(":checked") ){
    $("li").first().before( $(this).closest("li") );
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="ui-multiselect-checkboxes ui-helper-reset" style="height: 175px;">
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-0" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
      <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-0" name="multiselect_name" value="Abkhazian" title="Abkhazian" type="checkbox">
      <span>Abkhazian</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-1" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
      <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-1" name="multiselect_name" value="Afar" title="Afar" type="checkbox">
      <span>Afar</span></label>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-2" title="" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-hover">
      <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-2" name="mmultiselect_name" value="Afrikaans" title="Afrikaans" type="checkbox">
      <span>Afrikaans</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-3" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
      <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-3" name="multiselect_name" value="Albanian" title="Albanian" type="checkbox">
      <span>Albanian</span>
    </label>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-4" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
      <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-4" name="multiselect_name" value="Amharic" title="Amharic" type="checkbox">
      <span>Amharic</span></label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.prependTo()` to move it to the top.

```
$("input[id^=ui-multiselect-tar-option-]").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest("li").prependTo(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes");
  }
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("input[id^=ui-multiselect-tar-option-]").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $(this).closest("li").prependTo(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ui-multiselect-checkboxes ui-helper-reset" style="height: 175px;">
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-0" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-0" name="multiselect_name" value="Abkhazian" title="Abkhazian" type="checkbox"><span>Abkhazian</span></label>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-1" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-1" name="multiselect_name" value="Afar" title="Afar" type="checkbox"><span>Afar</span></label>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-2" title="" class="ui-corner-all ui-state-hover">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-2" name="mmultiselect_name" value="Afrikaans" title="Afrikaans" type="checkbox"><span>Afrikaans</span></label>
  </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-3" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-3" name="multiselect_name" value="Albanian" title="Albanian" type="checkbox"><span>Albanian</span></label> </li>
  <li class=" ">
    <label for="ui-multiselect-tar-option-4" title="" class="ui-corner-all">
        <input id="ui-multiselect-tar-option-4" name="multiselect_name" value="Amharic" title="Amharic" type="checkbox"><span>Amharic</span></label>
  </li>
```

Comment: @Prabhagaran No problem, happy to help

Comment: Carsten ; (semi colon)  missing $(this).closest("li").prependTo(".ui-multiselect-checkboxes");

Comment: I see, But remember the code will work just fine without